# Separated JOIN form main INNER JOINS's

Tags: sql

I want to INNER JOIN some tables and then insert a condition where the entries of a table are dependant on another table (that was not joined with the others)

Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A AS a
INNER JOIN TABLE_B AS b ON b.id_b=a.id_a
INNER JOIN TABLE_C AS c ON c.id_c=b.id_b
```

Now I want to add a condition (possibly a "WHERE" clause) that only selects the values in a field in TABLE_C that match another condition, the existence of a value in a field in TABLE_D

Possible statement:

WHERE c.code=d.another_code AND d.reg_number LIKE 999%

How do i declare in the query the TABLE_D, since I do not want to Join it with the others?

In other words, I want to intersect 3 sets (A,B,C) and the other one (set D) is intersected only with set C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The title of the question *Run-time error '13': ...* doesn't seem to match the content so I'll just answer the SQL part.

Maybe this is what you want?

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A AS a
INNER JOIN TABLE_B AS b ON b.id_b=a.id_a
INNER JOIN TABLE_C AS c ON c.id_c=b.id_b
WHERE c.code = -- or possiby IN instead of =
(SELECT another_code FROM TABLE_D WHERE another_code LIKE '999%')
```

If the subquery can return multiple rows you need to use `WHERE c.code IN` instead of `WHERE c.code =`

Comment: Thats exactly what I wanted. Many thanks. Sorry about the title of the question